# ADODBAPI SQL query

Tags: python, sql

I have a python SQL query which is intended to call a procedure and then return that query in results however with the below code I only get this output:

```
adodbapi.adodbapi._SQLrows object at 0x0000000004CDE278
```

instead of it selecting the rows and data that it should be grabbing, I don't know anything about SQL and limited python so be gentle :)

```
# Connect to the SQL DB

conn = adodbapi.connect("Provider=SQLOLEDB; SERVER=xx.x.x.x; Initial Catalog=master_db;User Id=User; Password=Pass; ")
curs = conn.cursor()

# Execute SQL procedure "

curs.execute('util.referencing_procedure', )
results = curs.fetchall()

print results


conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the results. Probably:

```
for row in results:
    print row
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Is there an easy when to then have this also output to a file?